# date not changing when using addDays

Tags: vb.net, date, for-loop

how to add day base on the value of text box?

this is my code it do multiple insert on database and change the day of the date 
based on the txtLedays.

```
 For i As Integer = 1 To txtLeDays.Text
            Dim currentDate As DateTime = dtpLeDate.Value
            currentDate.AddDays(i)
            Dim message As String = "Schedule Save Complete"
            query = "Insert Into tbldtr(Empid,Empname,department,empdate)values('" & txtLeID.Text & "', '" & txtEmpName.Text & "','" & txtDept.Text & "','" & currentDate & "')"
            dbEdit(query, message)
            frmSchedule.dgvSched.Rows.Clear()
            frmSchedule.generateSched()
        Next i
```

for example:

if input 2 on txtLedays the output should be like this

[image]

but my problem is the date is not changing

[image]

Comment: Its a function - assign the return `currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(i)`.  Test your code with an employee name like `D'Angelo Barksdale` or `Tommy O'Brien`

Comment: http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327